# Which spherical harmonic function will correspond to such a representation?

Tags: harmonic-analysis

On [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics) there's a figure displaying "visual representations of the first few spherical harmonics."

I was wondering exactly which spherical harmonic function will generate a representation like [this](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-CdOCmZ6TJHI/UUg9Blx2q6I/AAAAAAAACv4/vEehOEqZ1kU/w378-h428-p-o-k/ScreenSh00ter_20130319031723.png) (red means positive, green means negative; I don't have sufficient reputation for posting images, sorry for the inconvenience :P).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [rotating images](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Rotating_spherical_harmonics.gif) from the same page indicate the values $l=3$ and $m=2$. In Maple notation it would be `SphericalY(3,2,.,.)` where the dots are angle variables (the usage of letters $\theta$ and $\phi$ for spherical coordinates is not consistent). The following Maple code produces a [vastly improved version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VOMu.png) of your image.

```
r:=Re(SphericalY(3,2,phi,theta));
with(plots):
S1:=plot3d([r*cos(theta)*sin(phi), r*sin(theta)*sin(phi), r*cos(phi)], theta=0..2*Pi, phi=0..Pi, color=red, grid=[100,100]);
S2:=plot3d([-r*cos(theta)*sin(phi), -r*sin(theta)*sin(phi),-r*cos(phi)], theta=0..2*Pi, phi=0..Pi, color=green, grid=[100,100]);
display([S1,S2]);
```

Comment: Thanks very much. It's really helpful :)